# How to calculate the average depth of a binary tree?

Tags: trees, recurrence-relation

My professor has said that the average depth of all possible binary trees which can be formed with $n$ nodes would be $O(\sqrt n)$ and has assigned the proof of this as homework. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: First of all, note that there are several different models of random binary trees. Second, have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree#Uniformly_random_binary_trees)? It contains a reference.

Comment: This paper contains some pointers for several different models of random binary trees: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01194678/document.

Comment: Can you specify which model of random trees you are interested in?

Comment: Also, in what context was this homework asked? What class is this? What techniques have you been learning?

Comment: This was given in algorithms class. The topic is tree data structures and algorithms.

Comment: There isn't any specific model that I'm looking for. Like lets say there are n distinct integers. The problem is to calculate the average depth of all possible binary trees which can be formed with those n integers.

Comment: Sounds like a bonus question. Ask the professor for hints, or look up the answer on the Wikipedia reference.

Comment: When are two trees considered different? What is a binary tree for you?

Comment: Flajolet and Odlyzko proved that the average height is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ for many models of random trees: [The average height of binary trees and other simple trees](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000082900046).

Comment: Are you interested only in an upper bound on the average height, or also in a lower bound?

Comment: The question wasn't very specific. So, I'm not sure. Thanks for the reference article.

Comment: You can’t expect to answer a question unless you completely understand it.

Comment: The article that you referred to has exactly the solution that I was looking for. The question was clear to me. It was only about average height. Nothing about upper bound and lower bound was mentioned which is what I didn't know.

Comment: The OP never asked about any random distribution and did not phrase the problem as a probability problem. They asked for "the average depth of all possible binary trees". Although it is worthy to notice that in random settings, a "random binary tree" usually doesn't follow the uniform distribution on the set of all binary trees of a certain size, the question as it stands is still a self-contained question that doesn't need to specify a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated which distribution of random binary trees you are interested in, but in many cases the answer is indeed $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$. See for example Flajolet and Odlyzko, [The average height of binary trees and other simple trees](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000082900046).